# How to iteratively call duarouter algorithm in a traCI simulation?

Tags: sumo

I defined the flow by giving the from and to edges. When testing some traffic signal algorithm, I found the network would easily come to a gridlock,partially because vehicles cannot find the dynamic user equilibrium route. Thus my goal is to make those defined flow (vehicle) find dynamic user equilibrium route in every simulation time step. I know the duarouter should be the solution. But how can I call duarouter in every simulation time step, how where should I incorporate duarouter in my code?

I followed the example code provided by SUMO website. Basically I defined a run() function which defines my signal control algorithm. Then I call run() in the main function.

Where should I inset the duarouter?

[image]
How should I call it in my simulation loop for make sure in every time step, the vehicles in the network can find its user equilibrium route.

```
dua-iterate.py -n <PATH_TO_SUMO_NET> -t <PATH_TO_TRIPS>


def run():
"""execute the TraCI control loop"""
step = 0
NSphase = 0
EWphase = 2
while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0: 
    traci.simulationStep() # this means let the simulation go forward for one step 
    step += 1 
    {signal control algorithm}
traci.close()
sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
traci.start(["/home/hao/sumo_binaries/bin/sumo-gui", "-c", "/home/hao/Documents/traci_test/randomnet4/random.sumo.cfg",
                         "--tripinfo-output", "tripinfo.xml"])
run()
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, does the duarouter.py only assign DUE routes when the demand file generates vehicle? I mean, the vehicles already loaded on the network, can they still update their routes considering the dynamic traffic condition?

Answer (score 0):

Traci is a control interface to sumo. So the basic idea is that you can start a sumo server and connect Traci to the server. Traci will generate the routes based on your network and trips files, statically or dynamically.

In the SUE case, your code

```
traci.start(["/home/hao/sumo_binaries/bin/sumo-gui", "-c", "/home/hao/Documents/traci_test/randomnet4/random.sumo.cfg", "--tripinfo-output", "tripinfo.xml"])
```

actually

- starts the sumo-gui server,
- and connects Traci (SUE) to the server.

To use DUE with Traci, you should use the `duaIterate.py` in `tools/assign` folder. But

```
traci.start(["python", <PATH TO duaIterate.py>, "-n", <NETWORK FILE>, "-t", <TRIPS FILE>])
```

only tries to connect Traci (DUE) to a sumo/sumo-gui server. So you should first start the server manually:

```
sumo-gui -n suedstadt.net.xml --remote-port <PORT NUMBER>
```

The `remote-port` option here starts sumo-gui in the server mode. Now you can connect Traci to the server with the `port` option.

```
traci.start(["python", <PATH TO duaIterate.py>, "-n", <NETWORK FILE>, "-t", <TRIPS FILE>], port=<PORT NUMBER>)
```

Comment: traci.start will execute the ' sumoProcess = subprocess.Popen(cmd + ["--remote-port", str(sumoPort)]) ', which requires **'--remote-port'** to be an valid option for the cmd. But does that work for duaIterate.py ?

Comment: I tested the method, unfortunately it gave me the same result as before, which means it is not dynamic user equilibrium. For vehicles that have already been loaded on the network, does duaIterate re-reroute them again? Or just find the one-time shortest path when inserting vehicles?